# Copying latest modified file from multiple directories

Tags: shell-script, files, ksh

I have directory structure `adc/asd/abc.20150918_150635.gz`, `adc/asd/abc.20150921_140748.gz` .... (where `.gz` file names contain time stamps of its creation). Many other directories similar to asd are present here, eg. `adc/gmf/abc.20150918_010738.gz`, `adc/ret/abc.20150921_140748.gz`, all of them containing files with time stamps.

I want to copy latest modied file from all the directories (ie from `asd`,`gmf`,`ret` etc) with single command :).

I tried `cp "adc/*/abc.* ."` but it will copy all of the files. I want to copy only the latest modified file (with single command). Can any one help me?

Comment: You can do this by using find command here is the link
[Find latest modified file recursively from multiple directories](http://www.exceptiongeek.com/questions/question/119/Find-latest-modified-file-recursively-from-multiple-directories)

Comment: Do you mean the _single most recently-modified file_, however many directories there are? Or if there are 7 directories, do you want to copy 7 files (the most recently modified from each)?

Comment: want to copy 7 latest files from 7  directories.

Answer (score 1):

To find the newest plain file `(.)` of each directory `(/)`, a two pass method to first find the directories, then find the newest file (by mtime, or `(om[1])`) in each directory probably makes the most sense. With ZShell, this would look something like:

```
% typeset -a latest
% cd $TMPDIR
% mkdir latest
% cd latest/
% mkdir a b c 
% touch {a,b,c}/blah; sleep 3; touch {a,b,c}/a\ newer\ file
% for d in *(/N); do latest+=( $d/*(.om[1]) ); done
% [[ $#latest -eq 0 ]] && print uh oh
% print -l $latest
a/a newer file
b/a newer file
c/a newer file
%
```

So `cp $latest destdir` should then suffice (assuming that any files were found), unless for some unaccountable reason you've enabled the `SH_WORD_SPLIT` option in ZSH, in which case you'll need to deal with quoting issues as other shells do.

Comment: sorry I didnt get that... I am using k shell... how to write the program?

Comment: `pdksh` looks somewhat less capable than ZSH, so would likely require `find` (perhaps unportable) or perhaps parsing `ls` output (ugh) or otherwise looping over each of the directory contents and then using `stat` to compare the mtime on files.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp $(ls -1t */*/* | head -n 1) destdir
```

This is assuming the complete list of files fits into the available argument list space (or you'll get the "argument list too long" error).

`ls -1t` orders its arguments into order of modification time (newest first, the `-t` option) and shows one file per line (the `-1` option). `head -n 1` takes just the first line.

This is substituted into the command line so that you end up with `cp newestfile destdir`.

Comment: sorry.. it will not work for */* . It will copy only one file from one directory.

Comment: The question led me to believe that you wanted to copy just 1 file from all the directories.